# What are the web safe Arabic fonts that will work across all the old and new browsers?

Tags: unicode, fonts, arabic, web-safe-fonts

I'm looking for a web safe font list for Arabic, but they should work across all the browsers including old browsers and IE. I know that Arial will do my work, but are there any other fonts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tahoma and Courier New worked well for me, it rendered a different arabic fonts. still looking for more though

Comment: Do these fonts work on Old Browsers as well. Have you tried that. Old browser can cause issues. Please add details to your answer. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I checked Tahoma and Courier New fonts with IE11 and they work fine. I'm not sure about IE older versions though. Also, they work fine with Firefox and Safari latest versions.